# React - Fix colour for Mapbox CSS styling issue

Tags: html, css, reactjs, mapbox

I have the following CSS:

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl.mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib button {
    display: none;
}

.mapboxgl-ctrl.mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib {
    width: 280px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.version-watermark {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

And HTML:

```
    <div className="mapboxgl-ctrl mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib version-watermark">
        <div>VERSION NUMBER GOES HERE</div>
    </div>
    <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" />
```

But it is giving the following result:

[image]

I would have expected my custom div to inherit the same background-color as Mapbox's CSS (as seen when I inspect element:

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl.mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib {
    padding: 0 5px;
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.5);
    margin: 0;
}
```

But Mapbox's div seems to be a bit more opaque than mine, even though they should be sharing the same styling.

Comment: why not just pass the `background-color` manually to `map-container`? you cannot inherit styles from siblings

Comment: Or you can put both elements inside a container and give the background color to the container.